# Multiple httpd processes running in Docker Container

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, docker

This is the `Dockerfile` I created for installing `httpd` on `centos`:

```
#Installing HTTPD
FROM centos:latest
MAINTAINER xxx@gmail.com
RUN yum install -y httpd
EXPOSE 80
#ENTRYPOINT ["systemctl"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/httpd"]
```

After building, when I run the container I can see too many `httpd` process running inside this container:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 httpd:4.0 -DFOREGROUND
```

Output of `Docker top` command:

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                2457                2443                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache              2474                2457                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache              2475                2457                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache              2476                2457                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache              2477                2457                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache              2478                2457                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache              2491                2457                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache              2492                2457                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache              2493                2457                0                   04:26               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root                2512                2500                0                   04:27               pts/0               00:00:00            /bin/bash
apache              2532                2457                0                   04:27               ?                   00:00:00            /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

Please let me know why so many httpd processes running and how to have only one process with PID 1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apache runs multiple processes to be ready catch up a client request fast, because spawning a server process is slow, so it is better to have one ready when request comes in.
You can configure their number in `httpd.conf` through [StartServers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#startservers), [MinSpareServers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html#minspareservers), [MaxSpareServers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/prefork.html#maxspareservers) and [ServerLimit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#serverlimit) directives.